# Как получить массив пользователей с ролями из другой таблицы для каждого пользователя?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

Как получить массив пользователей с ролями из другой таблицы для каждого пользователя? Есть таблицы `users`(id, name, email, email_verified_at, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at) и `roles`(id, name, created_at, updated_at). Нужно отобразить на UI сводную таблицу пользователи и их роли.

Так же есть связующая таблица `role_user`:

```
[ id | user_id | role_id ]
```

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
...
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

Результат ожидаемый такой, только у пользователей разные, соответствующие им права:
[image: Готовый вариант]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если честно, то вопрос плохо сформулирован. Если тебе нужно выводить user_id, role_id то просто выводи свою связующую таблицу. Не показано какие поля есть в таблицах users, roles. Если

> return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');

показывает поля, то какой смысл делать 2 таблицы с одинаковыми значениями. Если же таблицы выглядят как

> users: user_id, user_name, role_id
>
> roles: role_id, role_name

то просто используй join по role_id

Comment: @NorthFace а какие поля есть в таблицах roles, users?

Comment: @NorthFace SELECT users.name, users.email, roles.name FROM users, roles, role_user WHERE users.id = role_user.user_id AND roles.id = role_user.role_id

Comment: а вообще я думаю более правильным было бы не создавать связующую базу, а просто добавить в таблицу users поле role_id, тогда role_id станет foreign key, и вы сможете объединить 2 таблицы по этому полю.

Comment: почти, только этот запрос не возвращает массив ролей, а создаёт дополнительный элемент массива, который дублирует пользователя + добавляет ещё новую роль, если их было несколько.

Comment: в таком случае, я не вижу возможности сделать это одним запросом. Я бы записал данные из role_user в массив 'user_id' => ['role_id', (тут будет дополнительная роль)]. И уже отталкивался бы от этого.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97919/discussion-between-north-face-and-ordec).